# Determine all real values of $p$ for which the following series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine all real values of  $p$ for which the following series converges:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(n)|^p$$

*Solution given*: This is the definition of a limit: If $|\sin(n)|^p \to 0$, then $|\sin n|^p < (1/2)^p$ eventually; that is, there is an $N$ such that
$$n > N \implies |\sin n|^p < \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p$$
However, this implies that $|\sin n| < 1/2$ for all $n > N$, which you already know is *false*. Hence, the limit cannot exist and the sum is divergent for all $p$.

*My question*: This only proves the sum is divergent for positive $p$, so we must also show it is divergent for negative $p$ as well, right? Or is proving it for the positive case imply it is true for the nonpositive?

Comment: But as provided the solution does not imply it is divergent for all $p$, correct?

Comment: Just to say it::  $|\sin n| \le 1$, so for negative $p$, $|\sin n|^p \ge 1$.

Comment: You still have to provide an argument to show that it is divergent if $p$ is negative.

Comment: Sure - but I think one can say that because of the above it is pretty clear for $p$ negative. But you're right - one should point out explicitly what one is doing/assuming for the argument to work/be necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For negative $p$, you can use a similar argument ; the series becomes
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\mathrm{csc}(n)|^{-p}
$$
and $-p > 0$. Then use exactly the same trick but you now need to know that $|\mathrm{csc}(n)|$ does not eventually lie in some interval around $0$ (you took $]-1/2,1/2[$ for the sine function).

Hope that helps,